# Socket communication goes out of sync

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, winsock2

I am using winsock2 api, tcp sockets with a server and a client.
I am using blocking send and recv.
Communication is like this:
Server sends query to client and client replies back.
Each query is of 1024 bytes buffer and client also uses same sized buffer.
Actual data to be sent can be different for each query and reply.

What I am observing is, sometimes, communication goes out of sync.
Server receives some garbage data. Even though recv call is blocking, it goes ahead with some garbage data received in recv buffer.

Why is the reason of this behaviour?
What is the solution for this?

Code Snippet:

```
SOCKET ListenSocket=(SOCKET)arg;
int iResult;
int CMD_SIZE = 1024;
u_long iMode;
SOCKET ClientSocket;
CbClient *tempClient = NULL;

// Listen to incoming connetion
iResult = listen(ListenSocket, 5);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) 
{
    LOG(ERROR) << "Listen failed with error "<< iResult;
    AfxMessageBox(TEXT("Listen Failed..!"));
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    return 1;
}
// Valid Socket
// Accept a client socket 
ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) 
{
    LOG(ERROR) << "Client Socket not created ";
    AfxMessageBox(TEXT("Accept Failed..!"));
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}
else
{   
    iMode = 0;
    iResult = ioctlsocket(ClientSocket, FIONBIO, &iMode);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR)
    {
        LOG(ERROR) << "IoctlSocket failed with error "<< iResult;
    }

    //disable nagle
    char value = 1;
    if(setsockopt(ClientSocket, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &value, sizeof(value)) == 0)
    {
        LOG(DEBUG) << "Disabled Nagle's Algorithm.";
    }

    int serverVerion          = SERVER_VERSION_NUMERIC;
    int clientVersion         = 0;
    char ver[CMD_SIZE]       = {0};
    char recvbuf[CMD_SIZE]   = {0};

    // Send Server Version
    sprintf_s(ver, "%d", serverVerion);
    iResult = send(ClientSocket, ver, CMD_SIZE, 0);
    // Receive client version
    ZeroMemory(recvbuf,CMD_SIZE);
    iResult=recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, CMD_SIZE, 0);
    clientVersion = atoi(recvbuf);

    // Match Versions to Check Compatibility
    if(serverVerion != clientVersion)
    {
        LOG(ERROR) << "Client-Server Version does not match, Client denied "<< iResult;
        AfxMessageBox(_T("\nWarning : Client-Server Version does not match. Please Use Same Version"));
    }
    else
    {            
        // Send Server details
        char hostName[CMD_SIZE];
        DWORD dwCompNameLen = CMD_SIZE;

        if (0 != GetComputerNameA(hostName, &dwCompNameLen)) 
        {
            iResult = send(ClientSocket, hostName, CMD_SIZE, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            iResult = send(ClientSocket, "UNKNOWN", CMD_SIZE, 0);
        }
        // Receive Client Host Name
        ZeroMemory(recvbuf, CMD_SIZE);
        iResult=recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, CMD_SIZE, 0);

        //Send Query and Recv replied back Results on seperate thread
    }
}
```

Code to Query and Recv reply :
sendCommand(clientSocket, databuffer, size, flags, extra params) and recvCommand(clientSocket, databuffer, size, flags, extra params) are wrapper over send() and recv() calls.

My problem reproduction rate is ~ 1 out of 10 times.

```
if( currentSendCmd->iCmd ==  CMD_ONE)
{
    // Send the Command over the Socket
    if(sendCommand(clientSocket, currentSendCmd, CMD_SIZE , 0, Client))
    {
        // Receiving response from client
        if(recvCommand(clientSocket, currentRecvCmd, CMD_SIZE , 0, Client))
        {
            if(currentRecvCmd->iCmd == CMD_ONE)
            {
                LOG(DEBUG) << "CMD_ONE command positive acknowledgement recieved";
                for(i = 0; i< Client->GetSomeCount(); i++)
                {
                    for(j = 0; j < CMD_ONE_REPLY_CMD_COUNT; j++)
                    {
                        // Receiving responses from client w.r.t. Gpu Info
                        if(recvCommand(clientSocket, currentRecvCmd, CMD_SIZE , 0, Client))
                        {
                            LOG(DEBUG) << "CMD_ONE command response no : " << i <<" recieved successfully";
                            flag = Client->UpdateClient(currentRecvCmd);
                            if(flag == FALSE)
                            {
                                LOG(DEBUG) << "CMD_ONE update no :"<<i<<" failed";
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {   // Recv failed, updated in log
                            LOG(WARNING) << "CMD_ONE response no :"<<i<<" not recieved";
                        }
                    }// For CMD_ONE_REPLY_CMD_COUNT cmds
                }// For some count

                //Recieving CL_CMD_TWO info
                if(recvCommand(clientSocket, currentRecvCmd, CMD_SIZE , 0, Client))
                {
                    LOG(DEBUG) << "CL_CMD_TWO recieved successfully";
                    flag = Client->UpdateClient(currentRecvCmd);

                    if(flag == FALSE)
                    {
                        LOG(DEBUG) << "CL_CMD_TWO update failed";
                    }                                            
                }
                else
                {   // Recv failed, updated in log
                    LOG(WARNING) << "CL_CMD_TWO not recieved";
                }

                // Recieving CL_CMD_THREE Info                                            
                if(recvCommand(clientSocket, currentRecvCmd, CMD_SIZE , 0, Client))
                {
                    LOG(DEBUG) << "CL_CMD_THREE recieved successfully";
                    flag = Client->UpdateClient(currentRecvCmd);

                    if(flag == FALSE)
                    {
                        LOG(ERROR) << "CL_CMD_THREE Update failed";
                    }                                            
                }
                else
                {   // Recv failed, updated in log
                    LOG(ERROR) << "CL_CMD_THREE not recieved";
                }
            }//CL_CMD_ONE : End
            else
            {   // Recv failed, updated in log
                LOG(ERROR) << "Unrecognised command";
            } 
        }//CL_CMD_ONE send, recv if
        else
        {   // Recv failed, updated in log
            LOG(ERROR) << "Recv failed : CL_CMD_ONE";
        }                    
    }
```

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are you specifying `MSG_WAITALL` among the flags passed to `recv()`?

Comment: For receive I am passing '0' as flag.

Answer (score 1):

You are neither specifying flag `MSG_WAITALL` nor checking the return value of your `recv()` calls.  As a result, not only may your `recv()` successfully receive only a partial message without you noticing (until the data turn out to be garbage), but it may also fail without you noticing.

Comment: In first code snippet I am not checking return values of send() and recv().          In second code snippet I am doing that.What does MSG_WAITALL do? All thread shall wait till current thread reads through?

Comment: For now I am adding error check in first code snippet and 'MSG_WAITALL' for all recv calls/

Comment: Per [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the `MSG_WAITALL` flag makes `recv()` block until it either fills the provided buffer (to the specified limit), the connection is closed, or an error occurs.  In other words, it prevents receiving a partial message, which otherwise may happen.

Comment: Thanks, I also read same on MSDN documentation. I didn't get the issue after adding `MSG_WAITALL` but we never know, as repro rate is very very low. I am still keeping eye and will keep this thread posted.